# Why bootstrap navigation button does not expand?

Tags: javascript, theming, navigation

I am trying to created a simple responsive theme using bootstrap but got stock at navigation bar in Drupal 6 and [basic](https://drupal.org/project/basic) theme. Here is the navbar that I've put in page.tpl.php:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
<div class="navbar-header">
  <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  </button>
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">MySite</a>

 </div>
  <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
  <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Tutorials</a></li>
</ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have removed all the native css and js files. Instead I have placed bootstrap.css, bootstrap.min.js and jquery-1.10.2.min.js into the theme and defined them for info and template.php. In the rendered page source I can see that all the 3 are loaded.

When I shrink the window, the navigation links collpase to button but then the button does not respond to on click to expected and show links. 
I also tried the very bootstrap [example navbar](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-default) but the button and drop-down menus does not work either.

What could be wrong here?

Can see in the source of the page that all the three are loaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in JavaScript: you should not include jQuery (and generally other libraries) through your theme.

Bootstrap requires newer versions of jQuery (I think v1.8+) and you should use [jQuery Update](http://drupal.org/project/jquery_update) module to upgrade it on your site.

Comment: I installed jQueryUpdate. but the button still does not work. What else should I do?

Comment: What does JS console say? Any errors? Did you remove the jQuery from the theme?

Comment: I installed jQuery_ui and jQuery_update modules. The system report says that current version is 1.3.2. I have also remove the previous direct reference to jQuery. Not sure what you mean by 'what does console say'. Thanks

Comment: The main question isn't tagged properly - I now see that it's a Drupal 6. jQuery v1.3.2 is still not enough for Bootstrap. I'm not sure if you can actually use it in D6 - quick check on my end didn't get any useful results. You will have to search a bit or find a workaround.